# CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class for bean with name 'encryptionKey' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to get the dynamic class name based on what environment the application is running.

Please help me out as I am totally stumped.

In application-context.xml file, I have something like below

Application-context.xml

```
    <bean id="properyFilePlaceholderConfigurer" class="some class">
        <property name="location">
            <value>myxml.xml </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="encryptionKey" class="${dynamic class}" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="some other class ">
       <property name="targetDataSource" ref="targetDbDataSource"/>
        <property name="username" value="${appdb.datasource.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${appdb.datasource.password}" />
        <property name="encryptionKey" value=" encryptionKey "/>
  </bean>
```

In myxml.xml

```
For local
<item key="dynamic class" value="local.class " />
For Test
<item key="dynamic class" value="test.class " />
For Production
<item key="dynamic class" value="Production.class" />
```

It throws the error below

```
g.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [${some class }] for bean with name 'encryptionKey' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${ some class }
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:206)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:493)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:348)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1154)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:760)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2147)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${ some class }
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:198)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:644)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:113)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:565)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:565)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
```

Comment: seems you are not giving class hierarchy properly

Answer (score 1):

`<bean id="properyFilePlaceholderConfigurer" class="some class">`

There is no `some class` (obviously). You need a valid class in that attribute.

Answer (score -1):

If your not bound to use xml, I would suggest to use .properties file instead. Below code snippet works perfectly. This might be helpful for you. If you have different parameters/class names based on different environment,  you can place one property file in each of the system. Spring will read the file from the system at runtime.

`applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd      
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context      
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

<property name="location">
<value>file:C:\\mybeans.properties</value>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="mybean" class="${mybean}"></bean>
</beans>
```

`mybean.properties`:

```
mybean=com.main.BeanB
```

Testing program:

```
package com.main;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class TestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
System.out.println("Context loaded successfully");
MyBean bean = (MyBean) context.getBean("mybean");
bean.show();
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)context).close();

}
}
```

Bean classes:

```
package com.main;

public abstract class MyBean {
  abstract public void show();
}


package com.main;

public class BeanA extends MyBean{

public void show(){
System.out.println("I am in Bean A");
}
}

package com.main;

public class BeanB extends MyBean{
public void show(){
System.out.println("I am in Bean B");
}
}
```